# Rationale for NORX/Ketje/Keyak not being chosen for the CAESAR final portfolio

Tags: sponge, norx, keyak

Was any specific rationale given on why none of the sponge-based AEAD algorithms (specifically [NORX](https://competitions.cr.yp.to/round3/norxv30.pdf), [Keyak](https://competitions.cr.yp.to/round3/keyakv22.pdf), and [Ketje](https://competitions.cr.yp.to/round3/ketjev2.pdf)) of the 3rd round candidates of the [CAESAR competition](https://competitions.cr.yp.to/index.html) made it to the final portfolio? If so, where can I find additional details?

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting question ,  here are some main points to identify major differences between Caesar winners and above-mentioned algorithm

**Background**

- **Norx** is LRX- Duplex based authenticated encryption scheme designed
  for lightweight and high-performance use cases.
- **Ketje** is Keccak-f-Duplex based authenticated encryption  scheme  designed for lightweight (except Ketje Major for high performance)
- **Keyak** is Keccak-f-Duplex based authenticated encryption  scheme  designed for high-performance (except River Keyak for lightweight)
- The winners of Lightweight use case are **Ascon** (SPN-duplex based authenticated encryption cipher and **Acorn** (stream based authenticated encryption).
- The winners of high-performance case are **AEGIS** (AES-Block cipher authenticated encryption), **OCB** (AES-XEX authenticated encryption)  and  **MORUS** (LRX-stream cipher )

**Performance**

- A [hardware benchmark](https://cryptography.gmu.edu/athena/presentations/CAESAR_R3_HW_Benchmarking.pdf) on Virtex6 , Virtex-7 and Straix-IV shows the Acorn and Ascon have the lowest Area/$A_{GCM}$ compared to Norx , Ketje and Keyak (0.16 and 0.4 on average).
- The hardware performance in term of throughput/ Area and throughtput/AES-GCM throughput for AEGIS and MORUS across Virtex6 , Virtex-7 and Straix-IV are very high compared to OCB , Ketje , Norx and Keyak.
- The software performance in this [chart](https://bench.cr.yp.to/graph-caesar/mlongenc.png) shows the , AEGIS, OCB and MORUS have lower cycles per bytes (higher performance ) compared to Ketje , Norx and Keyak.

**Security**

- A paper presented in FSE 17 (cryptanalysis of NORX2) concluded Almost practical forgery and key recovery attack on NORX v2.0.

**Further Details**

- [ATHENa](https://cryptography.gmu.edu/athena/index.php?id=CAESAR) project is hardware benchmark of Caesar candidates
- [eBACS: ECRYPT Benchmarking of Cryptographic Systems](https://bench.cr.yp.to/ebaead.html)

**PS:Iam happy to see if someone provide more selection rationals.**

[image: Hardware benchmark]